# Angular 13 animation Hostlistener doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have created an small animation with a state which works well in general. It simply fade in/out the `div`. Like this:

```
<div class="grid-container" [@pageFadeInOut]="pageAnimationState" (@pageFadeInOut.done)="pageAnimationState = false">
    ...
</div>
```

The animation is defined in separate file, is imported to the component and looks like this:

```
// prettier-ignore
export const pageAnimation = [
    trigger('pageFadeInOut', [
        // States that can occur from viewing the front panel
        state(
            'true',
            style({
                opacity: 0,
            })
        ),
        state(
            'false',
            style({
                opacity: 1,
            })
        ),
        // Front animations when landing on page
        transition('true => false', animate(500)),
        transition('flase => true', animate(500)),
    ]),
];
```

Now I tried to simplify my code a bit more and would like to bring the `start` and `done` callbacks to the component via a `HostListener`. Like this:

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { slideAnimation, creditAnimation, pageAnimation } from './animations';

@Component({
    template: 'app-anim',
    animations: [slideAnimation, creditAnimation, pageAnimation],
})
export class AnimComponent {

    @HostListener('@pageFadeInOut.start', ['$event'])
    animationStart(event: AnimationEvent) {
        console.log('start');
    }

    @HostListener('@pageFadeInOut.done', ['$event'])
    animationDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
        console.log('end');
    }

    ...
}
```

But the `HostListener` didn't fire and I'm wondering why?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your example ?